# Determine if a section is in view

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, event-handling, dom

i am currently learning to do things with vanilla Javascript. No plugins, libraries or code snippets. I want to do things on my own, so that I understand 100% of what is happening.

I wrote a little script which checks, if a section of the page is in view.

Now, the script works as expected, but I was wondering, if I had accomplished the task in a good way. I am especially unsure about looping over the sections in a scroll event. I would love to get some feedback on this. [Example page](http://dennisfink.de/projects/scrollOn/scrollOnBeispiel.html?fbclid=IwAR0vTfDImiujqW-yZdt5ovb-ii3EhCo3jxNXnM65SfbGOAENXTUrGYpJIrg)

Here is the code

```
(function () {
    // Store all panels in variable
    const panels = document.querySelectorAll(".panel");

    // Window on load event
    window.addEventListener("load", () => {
        let scrollTop = window.scrollY;
        let windowHeight = window.innerHeight;
        let documentHeight = document.body.offsetHeight;

        panels.forEach( panel => {
            if(scrollTop == panel.offsetTop ){
                panel.classList.add("is-visible");
            }
        });
    }); // end of load event

    // Window on scroll event
    window.addEventListener("scroll", () => {
        let scrollTop = window.scrollY;
        let windowHeight = window.innerHeight;
        let documentHeight = document.body.offsetHeight;

        panels.forEach( panel => {
            if(scrollTop >= panel.offsetTop - ( windowHeight / 2)){
                panel.classList.add("is-visible");
            } else {
                panel.classList.remove("is-visible");
            }
            if(scrollTop >= (panel.offsetTop + panel.clientHeight) - ( windowHeight / 2) ) {
                panel.classList.remove("is-visible");
            }
        });

    }); // end of scroll event
})();
```

**APPENDIX**

So I refactored the code as follows. I am still not sure about things like the IIFs.

```
(function(){


            const panels = document.querySelectorAll(".panel");
            let scrolling = false;


            (function windowOnLoad () {

                // Window on load event
                window.addEventListener("load", () => {
                    let scrollTop = window.scrollY;
                    let windowHeight = window.innerHeight;
                    let documentHeight = document.body.offsetHeight;

                    panels.forEach( panel => {
                        if(scrollTop == panel.offsetTop ){
                            panel.classList.add("is-visible");
                        }
                    });
                }); // end of load event
            })();


            (function windowOnSCroll(){
                window.addEventListener("scroll", () => {
                    scrolling = true;
                }); 
            })();


            setInterval( function() {
              if (scrolling) {
                scrolling = false;
                let scrollTop = window.scrollY;
                let windowHeight = window.innerHeight;
                let documentHeight = document.body.offsetHeight;

                panels.forEach( panel => {
                    if(scrollTop >= panel.offsetTop - ( windowHeight / 2)){
                        panel.classList.add("is-visible");
                    } else {
                        panel.classList.remove("is-visible");
                    }
                    if(scrollTop >= (panel.offsetTop + panel.clientHeight) - ( windowHeight / 2) ) {
                        panel.classList.remove("is-visible");
                    }
                });

              }
            }, 250 );


        })();
```

Comment: Hey, just a small tip. The scroll event fires a lot, and this may cause performance issues, you can resolve this by debouncing the event.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Actually I have never heart about debouncing events. I just did a quick research. So, what would be a good way to debounce? Depending on pixels or on time?

Comment: I suggest something like this: https://www.google.com/amp/s/benmarshall.me/attaching-javascript-handlers-to-scroll-events/amp/

Answer (score 2):

> *I am especially unsure about looping over the sections in a scroll event.*

There doesn't seem to be much of an alternative. One could select all elements with class name `is-visible`:

```
const visible = document.getElementsByClassName('is-visible');
```

Note that that collection is live, meaning it will be updated dynamically as the DOM changes, so there isn't any reason to re-query the DOM for those.

In the version that attempts to debounce the DOM updates, the IIFEs seem a bit excessive. Is the goal to limit scope of variables?

---

The function passed to `panels.forEach()` could be simplified:

> ```
> panel => {
>     if(scrollTop >= panel.offsetTop - ( windowHeight / 2)){
>         panel.classList.add("is-visible");
>     } else {
>         panel.classList.remove("is-visible");
>     }
>     if(scrollTop >= (panel.offsetTop + panel.clientHeight) - ( windowHeight / 2) ) {
>         panel.classList.remove("is-visible");
>     }
> }
> ```

This can be simplified by calling [`Element.classList.toggle()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList#Methods) with two arguments.

```
panel => {
    let addClass = scrollTop >= panel.offsetTop - ( windowHeight / 2);

    if(scrollTop >= (panel.offsetTop + panel.clientHeight) - ( windowHeight / 2) ) {
        addClass = false;
    }
    panel.classList.toggle("is-visible", addClass);
}
```

---

> ```
> const panels = document.querySelectorAll(".panel");
> ```

In most browsers it would generally be quicker to fetch the game squares using [`document.getElementsByClassName()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getElementsByClassName), but that would return a live collection (refer to [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39213298/1575353) for an explanation).

```
 const panels = [...document.getElementsByClassName("panel")];
```

---

The debounced version looks a little bit un-efficient because it uses an interval so that function gets executed more than it needs to.

There are also many arguments not to use `setInterval` and `setTimeout` - e.g. [blindman67's SO Post *Why is requestAnimationFrame better than setInterval or setTimeout*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38709923/1575353)

The functionality from the `setInterval` callback could be put into a function called `checkVisibility`. Then the scroll handler could be simplified to use [`requestAnimationFrame()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame)

```
let timeout;
window.addEventListener("scroll", _ => {
    if (timeout) {
        window.cancelAnimationFrame(timeout);
    }
    timeout = window.requestAnimationFrame(checkVisibility);
});
```